# How to use glReadPixels to read pixels to bitmap in Android NDK?

Tags: opengl-es

I use glReadPixels to read pixels data to bitmap, and get a wrong bitmap.
Main code is blow:

jni code

```
jint size = width * height * 4;

        GLubyte *pixels = static_cast<GLubyte *>(malloc(size));
glReadPixels(
            0,
            0,
            width,
            height,
            GL_RGBA,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            pixels
)
```

kotlin code

```
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                var dataBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(pixels)
                dataBuf.rewind()
                bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(dataBuf)
```

And get the wrong bitmap like blow
[image]

The correct one should like this
[image]

Anyone can tell me where is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the texture has been rotated and the sort to read pixels has been changed.